# Modifying an object's attributes within an inner class

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, final, android-seekbar

I have an implementation of ArrayAdapter here that's responsible for populating a listview which displaying multiple views, among which a seekbar.
Right now, I'm trying to implement a OnSeekBarChangeListener for these seekbars. I have a TextView next to the seekbar displaying the current progress. However, I am running into issues with updating this TextView whenever the user moves the seekbar. When the onProgessChanged method is called, I can't just call *competenceItem.currentValue.setText(progress)* because then the competenceItem object would have to be declared final. Now if I were to do this, my else clause wouldn't be working anymore as I obviously can't assign a new value to a final object.

What would be the best course of action here?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View row = convertView;
    CompetenceItem competenceItem = null;
    if (row == null) {

        ...

        competenceItem = new CompetenceItem();
        competenceItem.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progressChanged = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
                progressChanged = progress;
            }

            ...

        });
        competenceItem.currentValue = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview_header_competence_current_value);
        row.setTag(competenceItem);
    } else {
        competenceItem = (CompetenceItem) row.getTag();
    }

   //competenceItem gets filled with data here

    return row;
}

static class CompetenceItem{
    TextView title;
    SeekBar seekbar;
    TextView currentValue;
}
```

Comment: Make it your Activity class member instead of local final variable

Comment: Make a temporary `final` reference to the same `competenceItem` object then use that in the anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try this but, maybe you could ger rid of the `else` clause asigning `(CompetenceItem) row.getTag()` as the default value in the declaration of `CompetenceItem`. Then you could call `competenceItem.currentValue.setText(progress)` in the `if` clause.

Comment: I don't think I conveyed my problem clearly enough in my original post. My problem is that the currentValue has to be updated whenever onProgressChanged is called.

Comment: Yes, but it seems you can't call `competenceItem.currentValue.setText(progress)` because `CompetenceItem` must be declared as final... but if you declares it as final then in the `else` clause you couldn't assign any value to `CompetenceItem`. So my answer is like this: declare `CompetenceItem` as final and call `competenceItem.currentValue.setText(progress)` in your `onProgressChanged` method (and get rid of the `else` clause, of course).